# how can I recursively set pemission to all sub directories of a directory specified?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

with this command

> sudo chmod 777 /var/www/

I get 777 on www but not under www/subdir1/subdir2 
how can I set all subdirectories recursively to 777 with one command?

Comment: this has been asked before, and it is always noted as a bad idea.  just for reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22383/how-to-give-read-write-permission-to-a-folder-and-its-sub-folders-and-files

Comment: oh I could not find it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-R` flag.

so the command would be `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/`.

This is, however a bad idea and you should normally do it one at a time.

Comment: ok thanx, I will use it wisely