# Set default owner/user

Tags: permissions

I'm a web developer, and so have set-up an old machine in the office as an Ubuntu Server, for the purposes of testing websites.

I've set-up LAMP and have created a /var/www folder, from which all my local sites are served. The issue is that of user permissions, i.e. any files that I copy into that folder (from my Windows machine via the network) automatically take on me (daniel) as their owner. The problem is that I want www-data to become the owner.

I did some research and saw that it should be possible to use setuid (and setgid) to automatically set www-data as the owner of all files put into /var/www automatically, so far I've not had any luck making it work.

Can someone help please? Thank you

UPDATE: Would this do what I want it to do? [Default file permissions for php user www-data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21985/default-file-permissions-for-php-user-www-data)

UPDATE 2: I've kinda fixed my issue by changing my samba settings. Using Webmin, I was able to go in and change the default settings (as seen here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/521/captureon.png/)

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed by the user by setting the following file permissions using Webmin:

- New Unix file mode: 664
- New Unix directory mode: 775
- Force Unix user: www-data
- Force Unix group: www-data
- Allow symlinks outside share?: Yes [questionable]
- Can delete readonly files?: No
- Force Unix file mode: 000
- Force Unix directory mode: 000

See:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can fire up a terminal and type:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www
```

The -R stands for recursive for every file and directory under /var/www and www-data will be the owner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that isn't what I want. I'm trying to avoid the need to chown each time I add a new file - I want some type of mask that will **automatically** set the owner as www-data :)

Answer (score 0):

first add your user to the `www-data` group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data your_user
```

You can then make www-data your group, temporarily

```
newgrp www-data
```

This starts a new shell. any new file you create will be owned by www-data.

You then make /var/www owned and rw by root.www-data

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www
```

On a "production server" I will keep files owned by root, and, as much as possible, ro by www-data , but this may not be practical.

You can make www-data your primary group with usermod

```
sudo usermod -g www-data your_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Linux systems [ignore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories) the `setuid` permission flag, but you can apply the `setgid` flag for each directory within `/var/www`:

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
```

This will make each *new* file inherit the group of the directory while the user retains ownership, e.g. `daniel:www-data`.

But, if you absolutely need the files to have a certain owner, you could set up a cron job to fix it on a regular interval.